# How shall I write max, group by, where, order by in one sql statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-order-by, window-functions

I need to find the customerID who launched the most orders in 1996. And I have written the following statement:

```
SELECT count(orderID) as orderNumber
     , CustomerID
     , OrderDate  
  FROM Orders 
 where OrderDate between "1996-01-01" AND "1996-12-31" 
 group 
    by CustomerID 
 order 
    by orderNumber DESC ;
```

And the result is below:
[image]

My question is  I just want to print the top customerID which is 65,63,20, but I don't know how to write it.
I think I shall use max here to filter the customerID who has launched 6 orders.
Am I right?

Comment: you should first define top cistoner by what criteria, and show us how ti get those informations

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Your query is invalid. Which `OrderDate` do you want to show? The first for the customer or their last one? Decide and then apply the appropriate function, e.g. `MAX(OrderDate)` or just don't display a date at all. If you only want to show the top count customer, use `LIMIT 1` after your `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner. My query is valid. I want to filter all the orders in 1996.  The order date match with the day customer launched the order. So one customerId can have multiple orderId with orderDate. Here is the problem. There are three customerIds who launched the same max orders. If I use LIMIT 1, it only return one customerIds

Comment: No, the query is not valid. Customer 65 placed 6 orders and you show date '1996-07-22'. So, you see it guaranteed that all six orders were placed on that day? Does your table guarantee that? MySQL should raise an error here and that it doesn't may indicate that you are running an old version. As mentioned, to get the query valid, you'll have to remove the date from the select clause or apply an aggregate function on it.

Comment: You are right concerning `LIMIT`. I didn't read your request closely enough to see this was about ties. You are right, that using `MAX(orderNumber)` is the answer to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL 8.0, you can use `rank()`

```
select *
from (

    select count(*) as orderNumber
         , CustomerID
         , max(OrderDate) 
         , rank() over(order by count(*) desc) rn
     from Orders 
     where OrderDate >= '1996-01-01' and OrderDate < '1997-01-01'
     group by CustomerID 
) t
where rn = 1
```

Notes:

- `OrderDate` in the `select` clause needs an aggregate function, since it does not belong to the `group by` clause
- a half open interval is better than `between` if your dates have a time component
- use single quotes for literal strings rather than double quotes

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL versions before version 8, you'd have to do the counting twice. E.g.:

```
select 
  count(orderid) as number_of_orders,
  customerid,
  group_concat(orderdate order by orderdate) as order_dates
from orders 
where orderdate between date '1996-01-01' and date '1996-12-31'
group by customerid 
having number_of_orders =
(
  select max(number_of_orders)
  from
  (
    select count(orderid) as number_of_orders
    from orders 
    where orderdate between date '1996-01-01' and date '1996-12-31'
    group by customerid 
  ) counted
)
order by customerid;
```